# RSA 1024bit decryption performance

Tags: rsa, implementation

i want to know how many RSA 1024 bit long key decryption can a regular pentium4  computer do per second ? how to calculate RSA performance and determine its remaining time ?

Comment: Note that RSA 1024 is getting pretty weak (see [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com/en/3/). I would not protect too much important data with it, please try and upgrade to higher keysizes or [ECIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) if you want faster asymmetric performance during decryption.

Answer (score 4):

Good link: [Crypto++ for pentium 4](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks-p4.html)

```
                            Milliseconds/Operation     Megacycles/Operation  
    RSA 1024 Encryptio       0.09                         0.27  
    RSA 1024 Decryption      2.28                         6.68
```

CPU frequency of the test platform is 2.93e+009 Hz.
I think the performance depends on the language, library and CPU architecture.

Comment: so 0.002 second take an RSA 1024 decryption with pentium 4 right pooya ?

Comment: @mario: Yes. Order of magnitude for RSA-1024 private-key operations (either decryption, or signature generation) on a Pentium 4 is 1000/second. This will vary tremendously depending on implementation (some are 10 times slower, or 100..), use of [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) (not using CRT slows down by a factor over 3), and use of countermeasures against timing attacks and other side channels. Public-key operations (encryption or signature verification) may be like 50 times faster.

Comment: @mario:If you are using Crypto++ library, yes.